# How Wordpress remembers which active editing modes are used?

Tags: wp-editor

I noticed that when I save page in Visual editor. Wordpress remembers it the next time I edit the page even if I clear all my browser cookies and cache.

In what section of the WordPress database does this setting is saved? I searched for it and couldn't found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress stores this option as user meta ({$wpdb->prefix}user-settings).

You can use `get_user_setting('editor', 'tinymce')` to get it's value (`editor` is setting name, and `tinymce` is default value).